# Como posso manipular um arquivo PSD para obter a posição das layers?

Tags: c#, .net, photoshop, psd

Estou trabalhando em um projeto onde nós temos um arquivo .psd (Photoshop) chamado "sprites" que contém todos os ícones do site.

Eu gostaria de conseguir obter as posições de cada *layer* para poder gerar automaticamente um arquivo css posicionando cada ícone.

Existe alguma coisa pronta que possa me ajudar? Ou eu teria que implementar isto?

Como posso fazer isto?

Comment: Isto deve ajudar: http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/

Comment: Vou fazer um "cross-post" do SO, provavelmente seria melhor se extrai-se as informações e traduzi-se, mas como estou sem tempo agora, postarei o link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499597/how-to-extract-layers-from-a-photoshop-file-c-sharp caso isso viole as regras, apenas comente que removerei.

Comment: Amigo, você pode ou utilizar o próprio photoshop para fazer isso(coisa que eu não recomendo muito a menos que esteja desesperado) ou utilizar a régua do PS e medir os espaços dentre as sprites!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O *Paint.NET* consegue manipular arquivos PSD. Com a *DLL PhotoShop.dll*, eu consegui manipular o arquivo PSD:

```
using PhotoshopFile;
```

Um problema é que layers transparentes não ocupam exatamente o espaço que preciso, então para contornar isso e ter tamanhos dinâmicos eu inseri o tamanho do ícone no nome da layer (`32x32-Nome da layer`). Dessa forma posso facilmente trabalhar com diferentes tamanhos em um mesmo arquivo.

```
PsdFile ps = new PsdFile();
ps.Load(file);

// ordeno as layers pela posição
ps.Layers.OrderBy(l => l.Rect.X).ThenBy(l => l.Rect.Y)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(l =>
    {
        // Separo o nome da layer to tamanho
        var nameTokens = l.Name.Split(new char[] { '-' }, 2);

        // o primeiro fragmento contém "largura x altura"
        var sizeTokens = nameTokens[0].Split('x');

        var size = new Size(Convert.ToInt32(sizeTokens[0]), Convert.ToInt32(sizeTokens[1]));
        var name = nameTokens[1]; // o segundo fragmento contém o nome

        var x = l.Rect.X - Math.Round((size.Width - l.Rect.Width) / 2.0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        var y = l.Rect.Y - Math.Round((size.Height - l.Rect.Height) / 2.0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

        // gero o CSS para saida, output é uma StringBuilder
        output.AppendText(
            String.Format(".{0} {{ width: {1}px; height: {2}px; background-position: {3}px {4}px; }}{5}",
                name,
                size.Width,
                size.Height,
                x,
                y,
                Environment.NewLine
            )
        );
    });
```

Dessa forma consigo mapear layers para CSS, não importando se o arquivo contém tamanhos de ícones diferentes.

Este [projeto no Github](https://github.com/brunolm/PSDMapper).

Answer (score -1):

Existe uma possibilidade de extrair o `CSS` de um arquivo Nativo do Illustrator CC (Ultima Versão do Software ate o momento) inclusive ele serve para outros elementos do projeto como botões, banners etc.

[Como extrair CSS de um arquivo do Adobe Illustrator CC](http://helpx.adobe.com/br/illustrator/using/css-extraction.html)

Isso não vai resolver seu problema no momento uma vez que o Projeto já foi feito no Photoshop (Prefiro ele para montar meus Layouts) mas vale a pena dar uma estudada no assunto.

Lembrando a vantagem de se utilizar ícones do Illustrator também é  gera-los em .SVG para não perder qualidade em dispositivo móvel, quando o usuário da um zoom na página ou utiliza a pinça para aumentar a tela também.

[Link interessante sobre aqruivo .SVG](http://tableless.com.br/imagens-em-alta-resolucao-utilizando-svg/)

Comment: Jean, bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Só gostaria de deixar uma nota que o autor da pergunta faz referência a uma forma automática de recuperar os layers através das tecnologias .NET (veja as tags da pergunta).

Answer (score -3):

Window --> Info

Usa guidelines para fazeres as separações do sprite, a janela info diz-te as posições do rato ou do da selecção. O resto é matemática.

Melhor:

Abre no Fireworks e trabalha com slices, na janela "properties" consegues ver a info que precisas.

Espero ter ajudado.